# next-auth and typescript issue

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth, react-query

In my program I am pulling the state from session, specifically the user.id which is stored on the state after authentication and prior to loading this page. The state loads perfectly and everything is good except I get the following error;

`Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }'.`

This is from my lines of code;

`const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
const { data: session, status } = useSession();

const userId = session?.user?.id;
const {
userData: userProfile,
isPending,
isError,
error,
} = useGetUserById(userId);`

Mainly the line ...const userId = session?.user?.id;

This is mainly from the fact that the inital object does not first contain id as seen in the documentation here;

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client

My big question is, how am I supposed to be able to call session.user.id without triggering an eslint error? I know I can disable it but I feel I might be missing a 'Best Practice' of some sort? I've tried many things but the deadlock seems to be the fact that at some point I need to call the id to the object to use it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried several methods that are mostly around assigning it to a new object then using that object but again does not solve the overall issue.